# SMS delivery status when using admin-update-user-attributes from AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito to send sms to users. Phone number is optional and configured after user successful sign-up, using update_user_attributes method, which sends automatically a text message to user. Is there any way to get delievry status of that message? I need that information as cognito allows invalid phone numbers while update, which I cannot allow in my application to exist.